# Call my Chat script from other Python script

Tags: python, xmpp, subprocess

This question is similar to other python from within python script calling but none of those are working for me.

I have a chat script which uses Python XMPP to send a chat message.  The syntax is as so:

```
python chat.py -c "recipient@example.com" -u "sender@example.com" -p "secret" -m "message"
```

script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
import argparse
import xmpp

def main(argv):
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('-c', dest='contact', required=True)
    parser.add_argument('-u', dest='username', required=True)
    parser.add_argument('-p', dest='password', required=True)
    parser.add_argument('-m', dest='message', required=False, default='')
    args = parser.parse_args(argv)

    if (args.message == '') and not sys.stdin.isatty():
        for line in sys.stdin:
            args.message = args.message + line

    jid = xmpp.protocol.JID(args.username)
    jabber = xmpp.Client(jid.getDomain(), debug=[])
    jabber.connect(server=(jid.getDomain(), 5222) )
    jabber.auth(jid.getNode(), args.password)

    jabber.send(xmpp.Message(args.contact, args.message.strip()))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(sys.argv[1:])
```

as you can see, it takes 4 arguments.

Now I have another python script which is listening to sensors.  I am trying to get it to send chat messages when it detects sensor readings so from within listen.py I am doing this:

```
...
import chat
...
chat.main('-c "chatto@server.com" -u "chatfrom@server.com" -p "password" -m "Yo Yo Yo Wassup"')
....
```

I have also tried subprocess.call but perhaps have not gotten the syntax correct. both python scripts are in the same directory.  So for those of you looking for a specific question, How can I call the chat.py from within listen.py while providing the four required args?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

parse_args() is going to expect a list of strings. For simple ones you can just `split()` on spaces, but in your case you have a complex argument with internal spaces so that won't work.

Don't include quotes in the strings. Those are used to allow an argument to have internal spaces when defined from the shell, but they aren't sent into argv.

`chat.main(['-c', 'chatto@server.com', '-u', 'chatfrom@server.com', '-p', 'password', '-m', 'Yo Yo Yo Wassup'])`

See more here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html#beyond-sys-argv